# How to start the Einstein Bot on specific keyword?

Tags: salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-einstein

I created an Einstein Bot on Production for WhatsApp Chat, I want it to only start only on specific keywords/messages, for example, ="test"

So that the bot doesn't reply to customers, as it is not completely ready. Please help, if you can.

I didn't find any solution, because according to me, there isn't any variable which can store the first "hi/hello" message from the customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it.

In Welcome Dialog Box, I created a dialog Box and typed a generic message. After that, I saved the response in a variable and in Rules I checked whether the variable value is equal to the specific keyword or not.

If yes, call the dialog to another dialog box. Check the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdWEI.png) for reference.